# CSS not working in a template with js while html file is in a folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, localhost

I am very new to using templates. My CSS is not working if I put my html in another folder.

I have realised the css was being applied through JavaScript which I am also new too. I have guided the link for css/js the correct folders and files but it still wont work.

The relevant files are `/Linear/index.html` and `/Linear/builds/index.html`(where the error is) and the js and css folders

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmmdybvbhvff0w4/Linear.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template used skel.js and the style base path defined into it. So if you want your other html file that exist in other child folder work well, you must change the skel.js file.

Also in your index.html file used "noscript" tags. Its mean is if your browser dose not support JavaScript then load the css file, So if you remove this tags it works well like file that exist in root Folder.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/init.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/skel-noscript.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style-desktop.css" />

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `noscript` tag around the css link will solve this;

So, instead of

```
<noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style-desktop.css" />
</noscript>
```

You have;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/skel-noscript.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style-desktop.css" />
```

You can download the modified version here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lewnpt0iy980i53/Linear-Modified.zip?dl=0